# What is the minimum amount of servers for a production mongoDB cluster?

Tags: cluster, mongodb

On the mongoDB documentation for a [production cluster architecture](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/core/sharded-cluster-architectures-production/) I read that the minimum amount of servers for a running production mongoDB cluster is 7:

[image: mongoDB cluster architecture]

Is it possible to share the routers, config servers and shards on the same servers (having 3 total servers each with a router, config and shard service)?

Comment: IIRC, you can run the shard and config on the same instances, and the router runs on your existing app servers, so you really can have a safe production cluster on three servers.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm using a load balancer to balance and failover my clusters, will I be able to use it for my mongoDB cluster too? I will need a three nodes cluster fully replicated on all three nodes, so one shard on three master nodes (all nodes have to accept queries and updates). Would it be possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The minimum number is 1 server. If by "production" you mean "fault tolerant" then the minimum number is 3: you have a replica set containing 3 servers. The config servers also run on these servers. If you want to include "horizontal scaling" i.e. "web scale!" as well then the minimum number is 9: you have 2 shards consisting of replica sets of 3 servers and 3 more servers as config servers. If you include your app, not just mongodb, then add your two app servers to the mix for a total of 11 (it goes to 11!).

Basically you are interpreting that picture incorrectly in two ways: your app servers are not part of a mongodb cluster and the shards (green boxes) are replica sets, which contain at least 3 servers.

Comment: Hi Mark, I'm coming back on this argument because I have a question about: I mean a fault tolerant MongoDB cluster. I understand that 9 servers are required if I want MongoDB to work as load balancer too, but what if I create three replica sets and use HAProxy as load balancer, like I'm doing on MariaDB with Galera?